# How to get all ListBox items on submit action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How can I get **all** ListBox values (not just the selected items) upon `submit` in an `asp.net` `MVC2` project?

I'm using Ajax forms like `Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", new...)`.

I have already tried to select all the items in the `OnBegin` event of the Ajax options but not all of the ListBox items are being POSTed to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution.

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" onmouseover="SelectAllItems()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function SelectAllItems() {
    $("#UnlinkedProp").each(function() { 
        $("#UnlinkedProp option").attr("selected", "selected"); 
    }); 

    $("#LinkedProp").each(function() { 
        $("#LinkedProp option").attr("selected", "selected"); 
    }); 

    $("#UnlinkedProp").focus(); 

    $("#LinkedProp").focus();
}
```

Comment: hey ..what is SelectAllItems()?

Comment: its a javascript function like below; 
`function SelectAllItems() {


       
        
        $("#UnlinkedProp").each(function() {
            $("#UnlinkedProp option").attr("selected", "selected");
        });

        $("#LinkedProp").each(function() {
            $("#LinkedProp option").attr("selected", "selected");
        });
        
        $("#UnlinkedProp").focus();
        $("#LinkedProp").focus();

   
    }`

Comment: I would suggest changing the `onmouseover` event to `onsubmit`. This way, it can handle situations like submission over hitting the enter key and clicking the button with keyboard selection.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {

        $("#myList option").prop("selected", "selected");

    });
}); 
</script>
```