# Submit All Data in A list box Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that has a listbox. The User can add/remove options to/from this listbox. When this view is submitted I would like to retrieve **all** the options in the listbox. In MVC I can only get the selected options.

I am not restricted to a listbox so if you can suggest any UI i would appreciate it also I need to do this on submit i.e. an AJAX save is not suitable.

p.s 
I've read [How to get all ListBox items on submit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599957/how-to-get-all-listbox-items-on-submit-action)

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [formcollection only holds the selected html.listbox items values? MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383101/formcollection-only-holds-the-selected-html-listbox-items-values-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has a good solution

[formcollection only holds the selected html.listbox items values? MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383101/formcollection-only-holds-the-selected-html-listbox-items-values-mvc)